# Pointer to method from template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a problem, I don't know how to create pointer to method from template arguments

```
 /* Pointer to function */
template < typename controlledListType >
typedef void ( ControlingComponent::*ptrMethod ) ( std::list < std::weak_ptr< controlledListType > >,
                                                   std::weak_ptr< controlledListType >,
                                                   nlohmann::json );

/* Function to add a component which will be controlled  */
void addComponent ( std::weak_ptr< Component > _wp, ptrMethod _ptr );
```

error:

```
error: template declaration of ‘typedef’ in

typedef void ( ControlingComponent::*ptrMethod ) ( std::list < std::weak_ptr< controlledListType > >

error: ‘ptrMethod’ has not been declared

void addComponent ( std::weak_ptr< Component > _wp, ptrMethod _ptr );
```

Anyone know how resolved my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `typedef` with a template, the language does not support that.  What you can do is add a [alias declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) using a `using` statement like

```
template < typename controlledListType >
using ptrMethod = void (ControlingComponent::*) ( std::list < std::weak_ptr< controlledListType > >,
                                                  std::weak_ptr< controlledListType >,
                                                  nlohmann::json );
```

and then you can use it like

```
void addComponent ( std::weak_ptr< Component > _wp, ptrMethod<some_type> _ptr );
```

Comment: I've known you way faster :P

Comment: @YSC I'm still recovering from my turkey coma ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver about some type You mean type's from ptrMethod or different ?

Comment: @JakubFuks `some_type` needs to be there as you have to specify the template type that `ptrMethod` uses.  You could make `addComponent` a template like `template<typename controlledListType> void addComponent ( std::weak_ptr< Component > _wp, ptrMethod<controlledListType> _ptr ); so `_ptr ` could get automatically deduced.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thenks! I have another question to You. How I can use it? 

addComponent ( ptr, ControlingComponent::addAndSave() ) Just like that?


of course addAndSave has the same parameters as the pointer

Comment: @JakubFuks You should be able to use it just like that if you make `addComponent` a template.

Answer (score 0):

Templated `typedef` aren't a thing. Either use `using` or put that in a class:

```
template < typename controlledListType >
using ptrMethod  = void (ControlingComponent::*) ( std::list < std::weak_ptr< controlledListType > >,
                                                   std::weak_ptr< controlledListType >,
                                                   nlohmann::json );
```

or

```
template < typename controlledListType >
struct some_name
{
    typedef void ( ControlingComponent::*ptrMethod ) ( std::list < std::weak_ptr< controlledListType > >,
                                                       std::weak_ptr< controlledListType >,
                                                       nlohmann::json );
};
```